# Why is the spectrum different when it's captured with Java Sound and the Adobe Software?

Tags: java, audio, fft, javasound

I'm capturing guitar audio notes (same format and conditions in both cases), with Java Sound API and the Adobe Audition Software, same parameters in both.  As a result, they (the recording) should be also the same in both ones, but, I'm getting a difference in the spectrum form.

The audio format values are:

```
sample rate = 8000
sample size in bits =  16
channel = 1
```

This is basically the code I have used with the API: (replacing the corresponding AudioFormat values)

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class TestMic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, true);

        DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        try {
            TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
            targetLine.open(format);
            targetLine.start();

            SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
            sourceLine.open(format);
            sourceLine.start();

            int numBytesRead;
            byte[] targetData = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];

            while (true) {
                numBytesRead = targetLine.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);

                if (numBytesRead == -1) break;

                sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, when I applied the fourier transform, I'm  obtaining next values, this is the array generated with the Adobe Software:

graphics are also different:

1. With the Adobe Audition:
   [graphic adobe audition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkxJn.png)
2. With the Java Sound API:
   [graphic java sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNcfD.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your scale same for both cases.

Comment: Yes, is the E note for the first string guitar.

Comment: The gist shown uses 2 channels, different sampling frequency etc.. Perhaps it makes sense to post a gist that is actually showing what your doing.

Comment: Apart from the spurious high frequency component in the Adobe graph it is actually not so different.